# How can I access the controls on my default aspx page from my class library, within solution

Tags: asp.net, namespaces, controls

My problem seemed easy but I really can't find the right solution. How can I access mg controls (textboxes, grid view, etc) that are located in my default.aspx page from my class library. An error (The name 'GridView1' does not exist in the current context) is being thrown. I'm wondering why since I already added the project where the default page is located in the reference of my class library. I also include it in the namespace.

Exercise1 --> project where my default.aspx page is located

ClassLibrary1 --. where I wanted to use the controls

using exercise1; --> included in the namespace.

What else do I miss? thanks!

Comment: Normally asp controls are consumer of components located in one or more class libraries, not the other way round. And anyway you cannot access page properties as you would do with normal objects. What do you exactly need to achieve?

Comment: @mamoo I'm actually a newbie in asp.net. Apologies for confusion. Here's my goal, to create 3 tier data, First I have my UI which is in default.aspx under exercise 1 project, then I have added additional class library that has one Interface(IDataPerson) and  one class (DataPerson). Then I'm putting all method implementation (add,edit,delete) in DataPerson class and declared those methods in my Interface. With that I need to access my controls from my UI to my class library to be able to do the said operations. Thanks

Comment: can you share some code ? how are you doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're working on this backwards, your class library shouldn't have access to the presentation elements, you should be (in your code behind) calling methods from your class library to interact with your gridview. You shouldn't be calling the gridview from the class library.

Comment: I'm actually a newbie in asp.net. Apologies for confusion. Here's my goal, to create 3 tier data, First I have my UI which is in default.aspx under exercise 1 project, then I have added additional class library that has one Interface(IDataPerson) and one class (DataPerson). Then I'm putting all method implementation (add,edit,delete) in DataPerson class and declared those methods in my Interface. With that I need to access my controls from my UI to my class library to be able to do the said operations. Thanks

Comment: The way I do this (and I use n-tier as well) is as follows. Presentation layer -(.aspx file and codebehind, you might be using inline code, either way it's presentation). Then the BLL (business logic layer) where I do all my queries to get data etc. Then finally the DAL (Data access layer, I generally use LINQ to generate classes for this and wrap methods around them, deletes, updates etc. So if you've got a literal ltMyLiteral, in the code behind I might go something like ltMyLiteral.Text = BLL.TextHelperClass.GetMyLiteralText();   It's not a great example but it's hard to give more detail.

Comment: Thanks @Full Time Skeleton, I found a good example same as the way you did. [3 tier architecture](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article71.aspx)

Thanks for the idea. I hope I can do it right since I just started learning asp.net last week :D